# The sql generated by flask_sqlalchemy is incorrect

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

This is my code

```
today_user = db.session.execute("""select sum(money) from tb_recharge where state = 1 and date_format(create_time,'%Y') = '2021'""")
```

Output results

```
2021-03-25 16:43:17,070 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2021-03-25 16:43:17,070 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-03-25 16:43:17,077 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'
2021-03-25 16:43:17,077 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-03-25 16:43:17,091 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2021-03-25 16:43:17,092 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-03-25 16:43:17,104 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine show collation where `Charset` = 'utf8mb4' and `Collation` = 'utf8mb4_bin'
2021-03-25 16:43:17,105 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-03-25 16:43:17,112 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2021-03-25 16:43:17,112 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-03-25 16:43:17,119 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2021-03-25 16:43:17,119 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-03-25 16:43:17,130 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test collated returns' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin AS anon_1
2021-03-25 16:43:17,131 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-03-25 16:43:17,153 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-03-25 16:43:17,154 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select sum(money) from tb_recharge 
                where state = 1 and date_format(create_time,'%%Y') = '2021'
2021-03-25 16:43:17,154 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-03-25 16:43:17,352 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
```

I hope `date_format(create_time,'%Y') = '2021'` but `date_format(create_time,'%%Y') = '2021'`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQLAlchemy. The percent sign is an escape character in python. To print `%` you need to escape it with an additional percent like `%%`. Or you can use a raw string as a solution:  `r'Percent %'`

Comment: Although there are 2% in the sql it generates, the statistical result is correct. I have been struggling with this%. It took a long time, thank you, []~(￣▽￣)~*